# Prototype blocking function on mouseover

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, mouseover, autoscroll

I get this function that, on interval, make an auto-scroll of a carousel.

```
function startInterval() {
if (totSliders > 1) {
interval = setInterval("next()", 7000); }
setInterval("Time()", 1000);
}
window.onload = function {
startInterval()
}
```

I want that, on **mouse over** some "class ul li" elements (each), the function startInterval() drives cleared, stopped. In short, on mouse over the carousel elements, the auto-scroll stops.  On **mouse out**, instead, the same function (and so the auto-scroll) should be restarted.
 I point that setInterval("Time()", 1000); function that's included in the parent one, should not be considered in these mouse-over/out events. It should be called onload only.
 How could I achieve my target? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I'm just taking a stab at this one, because its somewhat hard to understand the question.  From my guess, you're trying to add `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events to all of the `class ul li` elements, correct?  If that's the case, here's how you do it:

```
function pauseInterval(evt) {
   clearInterval(interval);
}

function resumeInterval(evt) {
   interval = setInterval("next()", 7000);
}

var listElements = $$('class').getElementsByTagName('li');
for (var i = 0; i < listElements.length; i++) {
   listElements[i].on('mouseover', resumeInterval);
   listElements[i].on('mouseout', pauseInterval);
}
```

I'd definitely bug test this, cause I sure haven't.

Comment: Please consider [`Event.on`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/on/) instead of individually setting observers on each element, if only for the sake of resilience.

Comment: Hi, sorry for being late. I haven't tested your code yet, but i'm going to do it soon. Time lack. How could I try the code, updated with 'Event.on' ?

Comment: @asnothingelse I've updated my answer to already use 'Event.on', so you should be good to go.

Comment: Many thanks Pat, and thanks to clockworkgeek too..I will test asap